# Print nothing when number is None

Tags: python, printing

This script

```
def P(t, n):
    if n == None:
       print "%s" % t
    else:
       print "%-10s %3d" % (t, n)


P('a'    ,   4)
P('bc'   ,  12)
P('defgh', 876)
P('ijk'  ,None)
```

prints

```
a            4
bc          12
defgh      876
ijk
```

when executed. Can the function `P` be shortened so that the output stays the same?

I had hoped that I could define `P` as

```
def P(t, n):
    print "%-10s %3d" % (t, n)
```

but with this definition, the script errors with "*TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def P(t, n):
    print "%-10s %3d" % (t, n) if n else "%s" % t
```

If you want to print n if n = 0

```
print "%-10s %3d" % (t, n) if n is not None else "%s" % t
```

If you have multiple args you can filter out the None values and use str.format.

```
def P(t, *args):
    args = filter(None, args)
    print t,("{} "*len(args)).format(*args)
```

which outputs:

```
In [2]: P('defgh', 876, None, 33,None,100)
defgh 876 33 100
```

Or replace the None values with a space:

```
def P(t, *args):
    print t,("{} "*len(args)).format(*[arg if arg else " " for arg in args])
```

which outputs:

```
In [4]: P('defgh', 876, None, 33,None,100)
defgh 876   33   100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def P(t, n):
    print "%-10s %3s" % (t, ('' if n == None else n))

P('a'    ,   4)
P('bc'   ,  12)
P('defgh', 876)
P('ijk'  ,None)
```

Comment: So, if `P` has many number arguments (`P(t, n1, n2, n3, ...)`) and I want to print them, I have to repeat the `('' if nX == None else nX)` pattern? There is no abbreviation? I must confess: in so many areas python is truly elegant, but here I am almost a bit disappointed.

Comment: If you need it for many values, you can refactor it out into a function easily enough.